# PHP Check if $this is valid

Tags: php, this

I have an included file in php that can be include from inside a class method or from global scope.
`$this` will be valid in the first case but not the the second.

Is there a way to check if `$this` is accessible?
`isset($this)` and `is_object($this)` seem to return `true` even not being in a method of a class.

Comment: `$this` is reserved word and refers to current instance of given clas, so you should never use it for you own, other purposes.

Comment: You should put this included code in a dedicated class method (or trait) and always use it from there. include in the middle of a class method is not "clever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you include the file in a class, then `$this` is accessible. So you should do a more stringent type check here.

Try using `instanceof` to determine if `$this` is what you want:

```
if ($this instanceof MyObject) {
    // in my class
} else {
    // not in my class
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

Comment: Although, it would be better to use a better OOP approach here instead of including procedural code into object oriented code. Just my two cents.

Comment: agree, I tell myself this and similar more than I should. :-)